# Which component does Stack Overflow use for sending bulk e-mail?

Tags: discussion, email

Which component does the SO team use for sending e-mail on the Stack Exchange sites?

Comment: `System.Net.Mail` for the most part...we currently use a third party tool for signing but we're about to change that (to an open source solution no less)...this would be best answered once we see how well that works and can share some experience/tips there.

Comment: Oh! I assumed you'd need something a bit more 'heavyweight' for that kind of volume!? Look forward to hearing more...!